# Cucumber using Ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I am working on Automation using watir-webdriver.
There are 3 ruby files, lets name is as File1.rb, File2.rb and Commnn_file.rb

The scenario is as follows:
I compute the count value in File1.rb, say count=10 and pass it on to Commnn_file.rb. I have written a class within a module which will hold the value computed in File1.rb.

Now, I want to retrieve the count value in File2.rb file. How can I do this?

Below is the code snippet:

### Commnn_file.rb

```
module Count    
 class Row_count 
   # constructor method 
   def initialize(cnt) 
     @count = cnt 
   end 
   # instance method 
   def printCount 
     @row_value =  @count 
     puts "#{@count}" 
     puts "#{@row_value}" 
     return @count   
   end 
 end 
end
```

### File1.rb

```
And(/^I print the row count$/) do
  include Web_url
  @obj = Web_url::Row_count
  puts "Step 2 count"
  # puts @obj
  obj.printCount()
end
```

### File2.rb

```
And(/^I print the row count$/) do
  include Count #Count is the module name
  @obj = Web_url::Row_count
  puts "Step 2 count"
  # puts @obj
  obj.printCount()
end
```

In the above code, the value that is set in File1.rb is not available in File2.rb, which is because every time the object gets instantiated, re-initializes the value.

Can anyone suggest any alternative way of resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it doesn't work because `@obj` are 2 different Ruby objects in two different files.

You could set a `default_count` for `Count::RowCount`. (Note that I changed the case to the standard Ruby one).

```
module Count
  class RowCount
    class << self
      attr_accessor :default_count
    end

    # constructor method 
    def initialize(cnt = RowCount.default_count) 
      @count = cnt 
    end 
    # instance method 
    def print_count 
      @row_value =  @count 
      puts "#{@count}" 
      puts "#{@row_value}" 
      return @count   
    end 
  end 
end

# file1.rb
@obj = Count::RowCount.new(10)
@obj.print_count
# 10
# 10

# Set the default count to 5 for any future RowCount :
Count::RowCount.default_count = 5

# file2.rb
@obj = Count::RowCount.new
@obj.print_count
# 5
# 5

# It's still possible to override the default value
@obj = Count::RowCount.new(15)
@obj.print_count
# 15
# 15
```

Comment: Hi!!
Thank you for the response.

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to thank the answerer, and if the answer resolves your problem, please consider accepting the answer.